# Entity Browser Modal closes on Exposed Filter Submit Button

Tags: views, entities, 9, modal-dialogs

I've set up a commerce shop that uses Entity Browser to select product images. I set up a view to display the selectable images which has an exposed filter for the filename, so the user can search for the name of an image and then select it.

The entity browser works as desired, but if the user clicks the "apply"-button of the filter, the modal closes. Same behaviour with an iframe as well.

When I set the theme to Bartik it works. When I set the theme to Olivero, the modal isn't closed, but the filter is not applied.

Would be great, if someone could point me any way to resolve this issue or just give me a hint where and how to investigate this further. Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was my fault all along, since I have overwritten views-view.html.twig in my custom theme and removed the div where the "js-view-dom-id-xxx" is set. This one is obviously needed when the exposed filter relies on AJAX.

But why it doesn't work in Olivero I didn't figure out tho.